# Determine which column the VLOOKUP will return the value to? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, lambda, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have two lists of employees whose shifts and tasks are dynamically adjusted on a daily basis. The raw data is pulled from an import, then the query is done for today's date. Once the employees who are working today are listed, their tasks should be transferred to another worksheet, in order to keep track of monthly statistic.
The daily stats are important because an email is sent before each shift start to the employees who are working that day, in order to notify them of the task.

I've managed to connect the dynamic and static values in the second worksheet using a simple function:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A998, 'Daily task stats'!D:F, 3, false)))
```

However, what I would like to have is for these values to be assigned to a column representing the date in question. I've listed the dates as a header row, and would like for the lookup function to notice the date, and use it as a column where to return the results.

It's important to have employees row static, so further calculations can be done.
At least that's my train of thought for now, of course if there are some workarounds I'm happy to hear about them!

Sheet in question is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OQycG5f-kU0AIbMFDV0QrYvI-IvTtvntOXYfx_1kdDw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYCOL(C1:AH1, LAMBDA(c, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A998, 
 FILTER('Daily task stats'!D:F, 'Daily task stats'!A:A=c), 3, )))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, this works like a charm! I didn't manage to get a hold of Lambda functions yet unfortunately, but now I understand it's a must.

Comment: Whoops! A quick test showed that "tomorrow" will delete the previous data. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If you delete the raw data it won't be kept after it's removed. Isn't it possible for you to stack daily the imported information without overwriting the previous intel? The formula would keep it organized overtime... If it isn't possible, then you'll need some code run daily to "distribute" the information prior to its deletion